Problem with outgoing (egress) traffic in Google Cloud Job with NAT and static IP
I have written a service that requires a static IP for communication with an API. I followed Google's instructions here https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip, and indeed, the traffic is now routed from a fixed IP.
The problem is that I observe random connection timeouts each time, especially with the first requests to the external API. To make sure that the issue is not related to a network problem or an issue with the external API.
I reproduced the problem with a very small Docker image that makes only a GET request to a requestbin once per second. I still experienced the same behavior. When I remove the NAT and the requests come from random IPs, everything works fine.
I cannot find what is wrong and why it doesn't work correctly with NAT and static IP.
I want to route all outgoing traffic through a static IP.

I have tried to increase the ports per VM and disable Endpoint independent mapping..

The reason that you are getting the random connection timeouts each time, is because Cloud NAT does not allow inbound traffic, please refer this Stack Link it might be helpful

Do you use Cloud NAT only for outgoing (egress) traffic? Are you sure that is not the external API that have difficulties to manage multiple connections from the same source IP? Might it have quotas and rate limits?

Did you check my comment does it help you to resolve your issue.
